# SQL query to retrieve value or catch all

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm dealing with a table in the following form:

```
  A        B
  ------   -----------
   1       value1
   2       value2
   3       value3
  -1       value4
```

In this table, the value `-1` indicates a catch all, if there's no other match for `A` in the column. This means, a query for `A = 2` should return a single record for which `value2` is the value of column B. If the table is queried for, let's say, `A = 6`, then the value for B should be `value4` (because it's the value associated with the catch all).

What's the "best" query to achieve this? Is there a better solution? I've scripted a small setup example in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35d1e/8), if that helps.

The database is SQL Server.

Can you help? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would write the query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 B 
  FROM mytable
 WHERE A IN (2,-1)
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN A = -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, B;
```

This statement has a hardcoded search argument of "2" (as in your example).

You would substitute your search argument in place of the hardcoded "2", obviously.

---

The CASE expression in the `ORDER BY` clause makes sure that the "catch all" value of -1 is a "last resort", the -1 will be the LAST value in the list, any other any value will come BEFORE the -1 in the sort.

```
 A  expr
--  ---- 
-2     0
-1     1 
 0     0
 1     0
 2     0
```

So, when I `ORDER BY expr` we are guaranteed that a value of -1 will be LAST in the list. After the resultset is sorted, the `TOP 1` will return no more than 1 row. So, the value associated with the -1 "catch all" value will only be returned if no other matching value is found.

Comment: I was checking your solution but can't quite figure out what the conditional ordering statement is doing. Although it works, what does `CASE WHEN A = -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` order by? What does 1 or 0 mean in that context?

Comment: The CASE expression in the ORDER BY guarantees that the -1 "catch all" is a last resort. The 0 and 1 returned by the expression have no meaning, other than specifying a sort order. The values are arbitrary, could just as easily be "1" and "2", or "99.1" and "103.3". What the ORDER BY does is ensure that the "catch all" is LAST in the list, so it will be returned ONLY if no other matching value is found.

Comment: Clever use of `ORDER BY`, although `ORDER BY A DESC` should have been enough.

Comment: @Isoliveria: Yes, `ORDER BY A DESC` is enough, if you have some sort of GUARANTEE that -1 is the "lowest" value. But absent such a guarantee, the `ORDER BY A DESC` is _not_ sufficient, and we really need to make sure the statement will work in all cases.

Comment: I am sure -1 _is_ the only such value (below zero) in the table but that was not in the question, so you're right.

Comment: @Isoliveira: I just don't want to give out answers that are broken. Your example doesn't show any values less than -1, but I was being careful _not_ to make invalid assumptions about a guarantee, extrapolating from a single example. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 2):

```
select top (1) A, B
from (
  select A, B, 0 as priority from t where A = @value
  union
  select A, B, 1             from t where A = -1
) foo
order by priority
```

Comment: this is what I was thinking as well; +1

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @param int
SET @param = 6

SELECT * 
FROM test
WHERE a = @param OR (
    a = -1 AND @param NOT IN (SELECT a FROM test)
)
```

Replace `@param = 6` with `@param = 2` to test again

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, this would be trivial:

```
SELECT b FROM test WHERE a = @var or a = -1 ORDER BY a DESC LIMIT 1;
```

However, MSSQL doesn't have such a trick built in--you would need to add a stored procedure to limit it properly.

**EDIT**
It seems that in 2005, they added some paging functions:

```
SELECT TOP 1 b FROM test WHERE a = @var or a = -1 ORDER BY a DESC;
```

should work.

All that said, this sounds like an issue of poor design; I would look at the application that needs this and see if there wasn't a cleaner way to achieve a default value.

Comment: What trick MSSQL does not have? `LIMIT`? [It does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx). It's not a paging function, and it's been around for ages.

Comment: this assumes that there are not other negative values for a that are valid. If there are, it will fail.

Comment: Yes, the  `TOP x` clause exists in SQL Server and your (second) solution is pretty much what I've written. I was wondering if it was a best practice or not in this kind of situation but since you mention poor design, what other database design could better be applied in this situation (fetch value or default)?

Comment: @hatchet - no, there aren't. In this context, `-1` means the _default_ value when no other match can be found. For instance, properties of unstructured objects can benefit from this approach as there's no need to specify the value for all properties in each object (just use the default if the property is not set).

Answer (score 0):

```
if exists(select * from YourTable WHERE A=6)
  select * from YourTable WHERE A=6
else
  select * from YourTable WHERE A<0
```